# Core Data - When already created Project

Tags: ios, core-data

In the creation of my project I opted not to use the core data. But in the course of the project there was a change and I need to use core data.

Is there any way to achieve this change in project?

I'm using Xcode 6 with the entire project in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the CoreData framework and the code to your project.

There is no problem to add CoreData to an existing project.
Check the sample of Apple to get example implementation or you can use external classes.